# Oracle Object Storage Client NullPointerException on request

Tags: java, exception, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage

I am setting up my object storage client as described by the docs:

- I'm using sdk version 3.17.0
- Tested in java 17 & 19
- I've used the config file with the python sdk and it was succesfull

```java
ConfigFile ociConfig = ConfigFileReader.parse(configFile.getAbsolutePath(), profile);

Supplier<InputStream> privateKeySupplier = new SimplePrivateKeySupplier(ociConfig.get("key_file"));
AuthenticationDetailsProvider provider = SimpleAuthenticationDetailsProvider.builder()
        .tenantId(ociConfig.get("tenancy"))
        .userId(ociConfig.get("user"))
        .fingerprint(ociConfig.get("fingerprint"))
        .privateKeySupplier(privateKeySupplier)
        .build();

objectStorageClient = ObjectStorageClient
        .builder()
        .build(provider);

Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
    if (objectStorageClient != null)
        objectStorageClient.close();
}));

namespace = handleResponse(objectStorageClient.getNamespace(GetNamespaceRequest.builder().build())).getValue();
```

When I try running the above code sample I get the following stack trace.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)" because "endpoint" is null
        at com.oracle.bmc.http.internal.BaseClient.populateServiceParametersInEndpoint(BaseClient.java:215)
        at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.ObjectStorageClient.getNamespace(ObjectStorageClient.java:874)
```

Comment: Did you check/debug if all parameters that you pass are non-null ?

Comment: Yes, all parameters are as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The endpoint requires the region to be defined. You can set the region in one of the following two ways:

- when you are defining the provider

```
AuthenticationDetailsProvider provider = SimpleAuthenticationDetailsProvider.builder()
        .tenantId(ociConfig.get("tenancy"))
        .userId(ociConfig.get("user"))
        .fingerprint(ociConfig.get("fingerprint"))
        .privateKeySupplier(privateKeySupplier)
        .region(Region.US_PHOENIX_1)     // please add your region here
        .build();
```

- when you are setting up the client

```
objectStorageClient = ObjectStorageClient
        .builder()
        .region(Region.US_PHOENIX_1)      // please add your region here
        .build(provider);
```

> I've used the config file with the python sdk and it was successful

The config file that was used for Python SDK would have information about the region. You can try to use the same config file for OCI Java SDK by using `ConfigFileAuthenticationDetailsProvider` instead of `SimpleAuthenticationDetailsProvider`. For example on how to use `ConfigFileAuthenticationDetailsProvider` for Object Storage client, please refer [ObjectStorageGetNamespaceExample.java](https://github.com/oracle/oci-java-sdk/blob/master/bmc-examples/src/main/java/ObjectStorageGetNamespaceExample.java)